# Custom Authentication Servicestack services running on IIS 8 return 404 for non authenticated methods

Tags: c#, authentication, http-status-code-404, servicestack

I am running my ServiceStack services web project (a non MVC project) on IIS 8, Integrated Pipeline (Framework 4.5).

Now if my service is not yet authenticated it returns 404. If it is authenticated it runs normal. 
I would have expected a 401. I also tested it with IIS Express and same code is returned.

Request/Response DTO's:

```
[Route("/common/init/{token}/{timestamp}")]
public class InitRequest
{
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string TimeStamp { get; set; } //This also prevents an unwanted IE request caching
}

public class InitResponse
{
}
```

Service:

```
public class CommonService : Service
{

    [Authenticate]
    public object Get(InitRequest request)
    {
        ...
    }
 }
```

Web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
        <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

By the way, I am using custom authentication, code:

```
public class CustomAuthProvider : AuthProvider
{
    public CustomAuthProvider()
    {
        this.Provider = "Custom AuthProvider";
    }

    public override bool IsAuthorized(IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens, Authenticate request = null)
    {
        return session.IsAuthenticated;
    }

    public override object Authenticate(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, Authenticate request)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Request Header:

```
GET /GlonecoServices/login?      redirect=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fGlonecoServices%2fcommon%2finit%2fsometoken%2f123456789 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost
```

Response Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/4,035 Win32NT/.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 14 Jan 2015 18:22:20 GMT
Content-Length: 328
```

Comment: Can you provide the raw HTTP Request / Response Headers for the request that returns 404? You can get the raw HTTP Headers from Chrome's WebInspector or Fiddler.

Comment: Please post the full HTTP Request and **Response** headers by updating this question, i.e. don't post them in the comments.

Comment: So I seem to need some login service if I look at the request header (which I do not have)? I am now authenticating using a custom route (.../smsauthenticate/{mobilephonenumber}/{code}).

Comment: Just added an answer, by convention it redirects to `/login` but can be customized to redirect to your preferred login page instead, when registering the `AuthFeature` plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For HTML Clients/User Agents (i.e. Web Browsers) ServiceStack automatically redirects unauthenticated users trying to access a `[Authenticate]` protected Service to `/login` page by default.

The `/login` page convention can be changed when registering the AuthFeature plugin, i.e:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(...) {
    HtmlRedirect = "/customlogin"
});
```

Comment: Thanks (again) for your great and fast help.